# R datatable with multiple sparkline types

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, sparklines

Looking to add different types of sparklines into different columns but getting stuck with the fnDrawCallback options.

Using this tutorial as starting point: 
https://leonawicz.github.io/HtmlWidgetExamples/ex_dt_sparkline.html

code works fine but when I try to add different sparkline types to different columns it does NOT work and just prints both columns as sparklines, when 1 column should be a spark_bar and the other a sparkline

```
bar_string <- "type: 'bar', barColor: 'green', negBarColor: 'red', highlightColor: 'black'"
line_string <- "type: 'line', lineColor: 'blue', maxSpotColor:'green', minSpotColor: 'red', spotColor:'',highlightLineColor: 'black', highlightSpotColor: 'orange'"   
    js <- "function(data, type, full){ return '<span class=sparkSamples>' + data + '</span>' }"
        cd <- list(list(targets = 8, render = JS(js)), list(targets = 9, render = JS(js)))
        cb <- JS(paste0("function (oSettings, json) {
          $('.sparkSeries:not(:has(canvas))').sparkline('html', { ", line_string, " });
          $('.sparkSamples:not(:has(canvas))').sparkline('html', { ", bar_string, " });
        }"), collapse = "")

        # @knitr table_final
        d5 <- datatable(dat_t3, rownames = FALSE, options = list(columnDefs = cd, fnDrawCallback = cb))
        d5$dependencies <- append(d5$dependencies, htmlwidgets:::getDependency("sparkline"))
        d5
```

sample data

```
dat_t3 = tibble(Location = 'Edmonton', Month = 'Aug', Samples = "14.1,13.6,15.2,15.7,14.2,15.2,16,14.2,17,13.1", Series = "14.1,13.6,15.2,15.7,14.2,15.2,16,14.2,17,13.1")
```

or found here

https://github.com/leonawicz/HtmlWidgetExamples/blob/master/data.rds

```
dat_t3 <- filter(dat, Var == "Temperature" & Month == "Aug") %>%
  group_by(Location, Month, Var, Decade) %>%
  summarise(Mean = round(mean(Val), 1), SD = round(sd(Val), 2), Min = min(Val), Max = max(Val), Samples = paste(Val, collapse = ",")) %>%
  mutate(Series = Samples)
```